# How to return everything after x characters in a string

Tags: java, string, substring

Say I had `String s = "This is a loooooooooooooooong string";`. Now say I want to cut off `This` and return everything else. How would I do this? What I'm asking is, is there a method that returns everything after `x` characters?

Comment: Read the JavaDocs - they are **super useful.** http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: @Matt +1, better advice than all the answers :)

Comment: Someone wise once told me: _"Teach a man to build a fire, and he'll be warm for the rest of the night. Set a man on fire, and he'll be warm for the rest of his life."_ Hmmm, maybe that wasn't the right lesson...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is. And that method is the `substring()` method, which takes an integer as its argument and slices off everything before the specified character position.

```
String s = "This is a loooooooooooooooong string";
System.out.println(s.substring(5));
```

Output:

```
is a loooooooooooooooong string
```

Comment: Thanks you so much fireshadow52. You have taught me so much about Java. :D

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `string result = s.substring(4);`

[`String#substring(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) takes the start index.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. :-)

```
return s.substring(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`substring`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) is what you're looking for.

Example from the docs:

```
 "unhappy".substring(2) returns "happy"
 "Harbison".substring(3) returns "bison"
 "emptiness".substring(9) returns "" (an empty string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [`String.substring(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29). It takes a `String` and returns a piece of it. Like most things in Java, it is zero-based. That means that the first character is 0, not 1. Also, `substring` is *inclusive*. That means it will keep the character indicated by the index, not lose it. Finally, `substring` does not change the original string, so you need to assign the return value to something. Here's an example:

```
String str = "Hello World!";
System.out.println(str.substring(6)); // World!
System.out.println(str); // Hello World!
```

Now, sometimes you want to take a part of the string that is in the beginning or middle, not the end. You can do this with [`String.substring(int, int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29). This has two ints, the start index and the end index. Now, while the start index is *inclusive*, the end index is *exclusive*. Here's an example:

```
String str = "Hello World!";
System.out.println(str.substring(0, 5)); // Hello
```

You can find both of these methods in the [JavaDocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). In fact, generally the first Google result for the phrase `java {class name}` is the reference for that class, so they're easy to look up. They're extremely useful, so be sure to check them out.

Answer (score 0):

substring() is the method you can use.

```
String word= "This";
return s.substring(word.length());
```